# How do I change the active file colour in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

Highlighted is the current file opened in the editor. How do I change the colour so it's easier to see what file I have actually opened / clicked on.

NOTE: I'm using the new UI on PhpStorm 2023.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box way to achieve that currently: [IDEA-68266](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68266/Highlight-the-currently-opened-file-in-the-Project-widget)

What you can do instead is to make the selection in the Project tool window [follow the file currently focused in Editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#scroll_to_from_source):

*Project tool window options | Always Select Opened File*

[image]

Comment: nice, thank you, i shall try that.
i did end up changing the bg of the project window so it essentially looks the same, but ill try this way too, seems a little simpler